# How to make square div fit into parent div

Tags: css

I have square div, which was squared by `padding-bottom: 100%;` and setting `position: absolute;` for child. When width of parent div is bigger than height, square overflow screen and scrollbar appears. Is there a way to make square fit into parent div?

## Update

Sorry for misleadig you. Yes, I want to fit my square box into parent div.
I've created new js fiddle for the example

```css
    div.stretchy-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0.5;
        background: darkgreen;
    }

    @media all and (orientation: landscape) {
      div.stretchy-wrapper {
         width: 100vh;
         height: 100vh;
         padding-bottom: 0;
      }
    }

    div.stretchy-wrapper > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        color: black;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .outercontainer {
      background: red;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="stretchy-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a mediaquery to limit `width` and `height` of the element if you are looking at the viewport in `landscape` mode

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  div.stretchy-wrapper {
     width: calc(100vh - 20px);
     height: calc(100vh - 20px);
     padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

In other words: if the width of the viewport is `≥` height, to ensure a `1:1` aspect ratio you could set the `width` equal to `100vh` (minus some padding, if you need to) and the `height` should be equal to the width. Also the `padding-bottom` is no longer necessary when this condition occurres.

> [Jsfiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/y1jm3z2o/)

---

### After your edit

Since your `outercontainer` is fixed in height, if the viewport width is `≥ 200px` then set a fixed width and a fixed height both to `200px`. otherwise use a psuedoelement to preserve the `1:1` aspect ratio:

```css
    div.stretchy-wrapper::before {
      display: block;
      content: "";
      padding-bottom: 100%;
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 200px) {
      div.stretchy-wrapper {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
      div.stretchy-wrapper::before {
         display: none;
      }
    }
    
    
    .outercontainer {
      max-width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px #9cb dashed;
    }
    
    .stretchy-wrapper {
      background: #9bc;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="stretchy-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: You helped me very much! I was desparate!

Comment: This doesn't work if I put div inside fixed sized div.((

Comment: Then create a real example you need to solve because there is no fixed size div in your question

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry for misleading you!

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to set width and height of the div based on viewport height (vh unit, as in the [answer provided by @fcalderan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55102129/10783979)), and then set max-width and max-height based on the height of the viewport:

```
    div.stretchy-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      background: darkgreen;
      width: calc(100vh - 20px);
      height: calc(100vh - 20px);
      max-width: calc(100vw - 20px);
      max-height: calc(100vw - 20px);
    }
```

This way the div will remain a square regardless of how the viewport changes (but without the need for mediaquery).

Comment: This solution doesn't respect parent div dimensions.

Comment: @microspace I'm sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question? As far as I can see this works like the answer you got from jcalderan, but with less lines of css. Although I can of course be mistaken. [link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0woryjf/)

Comment: If I place `stretchy-wrapper` inside other div and set, for example, width for this div, `stretchy-wrapper` won't fit into this div, because it uses vh and wv units to set its size.

Comment: @microspace Aha, no then it won't work, that is true :)

Comment: Just to be clear: giving the stretchy-wrapper a fixed width and setting it equal to the height of your outer-container is out of the question? (of course then also changing the padding-bottom to same amount of pixels)